# Spring AOP applying advice to listener method

Tags: java, spring, listener, sip, spring-aop

I'm using Spring AOP in my application for statistics logging purpose. And I'm stuck on this issue - applying advice on a method that is in a listener class.

It seems like spring cannot apply advice on the method that is invoked by the container. I've this listener:

```
@SipListener
public class MyListener implements ContainerListener {
    public void onCongestionControlStarted(CongestionControlEvent event) {
        // Want to apply advice on this method.
    }
}
```

This a listener in my SIP application. And I want to apply a @Before advice on the above method. Is that even possible?

After searching through internet for quite some days now, the approach I've taken is - created a temporary bean, and added a `congesionControlStarted()` method there, and invoked it from listener. And then I applied advice to that method. It worked, but really seems to be an awkward workaround.

Any inputs?

Just FYI, SIPListener is similar to HTTPListener. Just the protocol is different. Functioning is same.

Comment: I don't know anything about SIP. What class/method makes a call on that `MyListener.onCongestionControlStarted()` method?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Just consider it as normal listener, as we have HTTPListener. That method is called from the container only - Tomcat.

Comment: Is `MyListener` a class whose instances are created and managed by Spring?

Comment: Then this is your answer: if Spring doesn't know about it, then it doesn't know to apply the advice. You would need a pure AspectJ approach for this, I believe.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Hmm. I guess I knew it. Just wondered whether by chance there is a way to do this without having to move on to AspectJ :(

Comment: And this is why the other approach you have works. You created a bean, which is probably managed and created by Spring (through XML or annotations), Spring applies AOP to it and it works.

Comment: You could try the [`@Configurable` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-atconfigurable) and see if it works.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Seems to be useful. I'm currently reading up on it. Will try it and update. Thanks :)

Comment: Alternatively, it might be simpler and have a ContainerListener implementation that looks up the ApplicationContext, gets a reference to the Spring managed ContainerListener implementation and then delegates to it.

Comment: @RobBlake And that is how exactly we're doing it right now :)

Comment: It would be useful for others that stumble across this if you could post your implementation as answer to your own question.